# 2017 Eclipse intersection with I-95

Tags: solar-eclipse

I am excited to see the 2017 eclipse in South Carolina and would like to understand where exactly the eclipse-path intersects I-95, so that I can plan a day-trip.

I have approximated at roughly Santee,SC, but would really like to overlay and pinpoint the eclipse-path intersection with I-95 in Google maps ([blue line in .kml file](http://xjubier.free.fr/en/site_pages/SolarEclipsesGoogleEarth.html)).  Unfortunately, the KML file does not show I-95

1. Hasn't someone already done this with the web version with Google maps?
2. Is there a simple process to either embed I-95 in the Google Earth .kml or
3. Command Google Earth to overlay the blue eclipse path over the internet connected map data?

I was able to plot Santee, SC (on I-95) on the .kml file:

[image]

Any edits to sharpen or clarify questions are appreciated.  I pose this question to the astronomy community because I think that someone has already done this.  See you at the eclipse!

Comment: Your profile says you are from New York, New York, but that's nominally a ten hour drive to Adam's Landing, SC. Your icon and the nature of the question suggests you are instead from Jacksonville, FL, which is nominally a 3.5 hour drive to  Adams Landing, SC. That's nominal. Traffic on I95 on August 21 to anywhere close to Adams Landing SC will not be nominal. I suggest doubling that time: a seven hour drive to and a seven hour drive back. Alternatively, get a room!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NASA has a very good interactive [online map](https://eclipse2017.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/interactive_map/index.html) which also shows highways.  It looks like I-95 intersects with the path by a wildlife refuge.

[image]

[image]

A note on planning your trip: there will most likely be a very large number of people who also want to go out to see the eclipse.  So be prepared for lots of traffic.  Also, depending on where you plan on going, you will probably have to leave very early in order to get a good spot.

Comment: The *width* of totality for this eclipse in the Eastern US is I think of the order of 100km, so +/-10 km or so away from this line won't make a huge difference. This map looks like it's only 3-4 km on a side, so one can probably look for a good spot somewhat outside of this view without a significant compromise of the experience.

Comment: http://www.wral.com/weather/video/16821861/ = an article on expected I-95 traffic jams